# How can I send the byte array for Bitmap to the main page in image processing?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am trying to send bytes to the "alldata.AddRange()" but I want to do that as line.What I mean,for example, I have a RGB view 640 * 360.Width of the view is 640.I want to take the view 640*3=1920(as a line) and make it gray and send it back to the function(alldata.AddRange).If I send line 360 of them I want to take the image.How can I do that?

EDIT:I changed the code just a little.May be it can be thought as sending data between classes through arrays and I need to send them in parts instead of thinking as image processing problem.

Here is the code for Form1:

```
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dnm2510img
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public FilterInfoCollection devices;
        public VideoCaptureDevice camera;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            devices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

            foreach (FilterInfo item in devices)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(item.Name);

            }

            camera = new VideoCaptureDevice();
            comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (camera.IsRunning == false)
                {
                    camera = new VideoCaptureDevice(devices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                    camera.NewFrame += Camera_NewFrame;
                    camera.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message + "");
            }
        }
        public void Camera_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            List<byte> alldata = new List<byte>();
            //byte[] line = new byte[360];
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            byte[] maindata = new byte[image.Height*image.Width*4];
            int count = 0;
            if(btnapplyWasClicked == true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < image.Height; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < image.Width; j++)
                    {
                        Color color = image.GetPixel(j, i);
                        maindata[count] = color.R;
                        maindata[count + 1] = color.G;
                        maindata[count + 2] = color.B;
                        maindata[count + 3] = color.A;
                        count = count + 4;

                        for (int k = 1; k <= 360; k++)
                        {
                            if (maindata[(count + 4) * k] == maindata[2560 * k])
                            {
                                dnm2510img.Gray.GrayFilter(maindata, 2560 * k);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                    //alldata.AddRange(maindata);
            }
            
        }
        
        private bool btnapplyWasClicked = false;
        //private bool button1WasClicked = false;
        //private bool GeriALWasClicked = false;

        private void btnapply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnapplyWasClicked = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //button1WasClicked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Grayscale:

```
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dnm2510img
{
    public class Gray
    {
        
        public static byte[] GrayFilter(byte[] data,int width)
        {
            List<byte> alldataa = new List<byte>();
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                int temp =((data[i]+data[i+1]+data[i+2]+data[i+3]) / 4);
                data[i] = (byte)temp;
                data[i+1] = (byte)temp;
                data[i+2] = (byte)temp;
                data[i + 3] = (byte)temp;
            }
            //alldataa.AddRange(data);
            return data;
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You're already changing the array. Do you need to actually return anything?

Comment: But when I do not return I am getting error.

Comment: ...and the error is what? You're not using the result here: `dnm2510img.Gray.GrayFilter(maindata, 1920 * k);`, so I don't see how you'd get an error just by changing the method to a `void`.

Comment: Yes, when I add void error is gone  thank you but do you have any recommandation for solving my question.

Comment: Not simply `alldata.AddRange(maindata);`?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Well `GrayFilter` modifies `data`, right? In `Camera_NewFrame`, that's `data` is called `maindata`, right? You want to add that data to `alldata`, right? So why not call `alldata.AddRange(maindata);` in `Camera_NewFrame` after calling `GrayFilter`? Am I missing something here? Can you explain more clearly what you want to do?

Comment: But when I say maindata it is getting all data(not gray scaled).I want to send 1920 pixel to the grayscale and make it gray and sending the other lines one by one and send it back to the form1 and when I send 360 of line I want to get a picture.

Comment: I am striving this issue for weeks could you help me for this code?May be I can change it as Bitmap.Lockbits but right now I should get data as line because I need to do this for product sorting and getting picture is not important that much I need to get them as line.@ Alex F

Comment: Is the end goal to produce a grayscale image? It is very useful to state the actual goal you are trying to accomplish in addition of the method you are trying to use. That way we have a better chance of telling if you are on the right track or not.

Comment: Yes but the view that coming from the screen is not important that much making the lines gray because while making  sorting of the produce the camera needs to lines.It is not interest in the view on the screen.I am trying to send the data when the data reached to 1920 to the gray function and make it gray and send it back to form1.cs as line.@JonasH

Answer (score 2):

This is how you convert a 24 bpp bitmap to grayscale and output it to a linear array:

```
public static unsafe byte[] ToBgr24To8Mono(Bitmap source)
{
    var width = source.Width;
    var height = source.Height;
    var sourceData = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, source.PixelFormat);
    var sourceStride = sourceData.Stride;
    var sourcePtr = (byte*)sourceData.Scan0;
    var targetArray = new byte[width * height];
    try
    {
        Parallel.For(0, height, y =>
        {
            var sourceRow = sourcePtr + y * sourceStride;
            var targetRow =  y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                var sourceIndex = (sourceRow + x * 3);
                var value = (byte) (sourceIndex[0] * 0.11f + sourceIndex[1] * 0.59f + sourceIndex[2] * 0.3f);
                targetArray[targetRow + x] = value;
            }
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        source.UnlockBits(sourceData);
    }

    return targetArray;
}
```

If you want to use a 32bit image as input, change `x * 3` to `x * 4`. The parallel loop can be switched to a regular loop if you wish.

Comment: Thank you I am gonna try to do with this way@JonasH but if somebody can fix it on my method I am gonna be  appreciated